# Javascript - reorder and reformat date

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a date displaying on my website in this format:

```
MM/DD/YY
```

I would like to convert it to the following format using jQuery:

```
YYYY-MM-DD
```

I would prefer to do it without a plugin. I was able to replace the forward slashes with hyphens using the code below but now I am stuck.

```js
var date = "05/23/21";
var formattedDate = date.replace(/\//g, '-');

$('body').append(formattedDate);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do what you require you can convert the input string to a Date object, then use the methods JS exposes to pull out the constituent parts in to the format you require:

```js
let input = "05/23/21";
let date = new Date(input);
const zeroPad = (num, places) => String(num).padStart(places, '0')
let formattedDate = `${date.getFullYear()}-${zeroPad(date.getMonth() + 1, 2)}-${zeroPad(date.getDate(), 2)}`;

$('body').append(formattedDate);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Curiously, does this method possibly change the date based on locales?

Comment: No, as the `Date()` object only accepts ISO or US format dates. If you meant the output, then also no, as we're manually specifying the parts of the date to use within the string.

Answer (score 1):

This method assumes all dates are 20XX. It splits the date by `/`, reverses that array (getting the `YY MM DD` format), then reformats the year to be `YYYY` and joins the array back together with `-`

```js
var date = "05/23/21";
var formattedDate = date.split('/').reverse().map((e, i) => i === 0 ? `20${e}` : e).join('-');

$('body').append(formattedDate);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

By using `regex group` and replace it with reverse order you can do it.

```js
var date = "05/23/21";
const formattedDate = date.replace(/(\d+)\/(\d+)\/(\d+)/, "20$3-$2-$1");
console.log(formattedDate);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{min-height: 100%!important; top: 0}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check the following code. Let me know if something goes wrong

```
const d = date.split("/");
var res = '20'+d[2] +'-'+d[0]+'-'+d[1];
```